# jquery daterange picker selecting end date before selected date lost end date selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I have below fiddler
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mparvez1986/21wbxqht/)

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    "autoApply": false,
    "showCustomRangeLabel": false,
    "minDate": "01/04/2017",
    "maxDate": "04/10/2017",
    "dateLimit" : {
    "days" : 60
    }

}, function(start, end, label) {
  console.log("New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')");
});

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($('input[name="daterange"]').length) {
            $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker("close");
      }
    });
});
```

First select date then select a date before selected date, ideally it should set earlier date as end date and later selection should be as first date. but it lost previous selction.

Comment: do you want left side date as end date and right side date as start date?

Comment: Nope... the left side should be start date and right side should be end date, like if i select 10th jan first then if i select 2nd jan , it should not loose selection of 10th jan and 2nd date should be start date and 10th jan should be end date

Comment: I thought you can't achieve may be or go though this link http://www.daterangepicker.com/